# Storing Multiple User inputs while using a loop

Tags: python

My intent here this to query the user for multiple inputs using a loop that stops when the user inputs and integer of zero. I need to be able to recall the data in a later line of code. With that in mind I'm trying to create a list of the users input.

Python 3 code

```
i = False
val1 = []
while i == False:
    if  val1 != 0:
        val1 = eval(input("Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 0: "))
    else:
        i = True
        print(val1)
```

Comment: Under `if val1 != 0:` you should not assign, but `.append` to a list. Like this: `val1.append(eval...)`

Comment: it will allow me to append the list however, I still run into the problem of it not breaking out of the loop by running the else. Is there a solution to check to see if the list contains a 0 in to break out? Essentially I want to call the min and max out of the list at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be cleaner if you use a infinite loop and break if the input is 0.  Otherwise, simply append to the the list.

```
values = []
while True:
    val = int(input("Enter an integer, the value ends if it is 0: "))
    if val == 0:
        break
    values.append(val)
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap the `input` call in a call to `int`, otherwise `val == 0` will never be true.

Comment: `input(prompt)` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, so it should work

Comment: This solution partially works, however it doesn't seem to break out after entering a 0 value. If you run it it asks me for another input from the user. We need the int value of 0 to break out of the loop.

Comment: It works as intended for python2, but yeah, you need to convert to int for python3